# Web and Daphne always restarting and not working properly

Tags: python, django, docker, redis

I've checked all I've seen, yet nothing is  working.
Please, I'm trying  to make use of docker  and all for the first time.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
 services:

  cache:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/cache:/data

  db:
    image: postgres:15.0
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=samuel
      - POSTGRES_USER=samuel
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***

  web:
    build: .
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--",
              "uwsgi", "--ini", "/code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=chollosite.settings.prod
      - POSTGRES_DB=samuel
      - POSTGRES_USER=samuel
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=samuel101
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache

  daphne:
    build: .
    working_dir: /code/chollosite/
    command: ["../wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--",
              "daphne", "-u", "/code/chollosite/daphne.sock",
              "chollosite.asgi:application"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=chollosite.settings.prod
      - POSTGRES_DB=samuel
      - POSTGRES_USER=samuel
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/templates
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

this is my base.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'pex0v$*b!kjl-bk2p%1y8rf!&jh+bqa!9t5e4@xnac-(nbi2wc'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'chollo_main.apps.CholloMainConfig',
    'chollo_cart.apps.CholloCartConfig',
    'orders.apps.OrderConfig',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'channels',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chollosite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'chollo_main/templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'chollo_cart.context_processors.cart'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chollosite.wsgi.application'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR, 'static'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'



# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field


PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.ScryptPasswordHasher',
]


CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
    }
}

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'chollosite.asgi.application'


CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'chollo_main:product_list'
LOGIN_URL = 'chollo_main:login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'chollo_main:logout'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'chollo_main.authentication.EmailAuthBackend',
]
```

the prod.py

```
import os
from .base import *


DEBUG = False

ADMINS = [
    ('samuel', 'samuelosondu99@gmail.com'),
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['chollositeproject.com', 'www.chollositeproject.com']

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
       'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
       'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
       'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
       'HOST': 'db',
       'PORT': 5432,
   }
}


REDIS_URL = 'redis://cache:6379'
CACHES['default']['LOCATION'] = REDIS_URL
CHANNEL_LAYERS['default']['CONFIG']['hosts'] = [REDIS_URL]

# Security
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

I get errors

```
    drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 681, in _parse_args
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

Please I need help.. The local environment is working right but once I try to even 'check deploy' it throws that error.

Getting this log on the docker too

```
cholloproject-daphne-1  | 2023-08-12 09:30:14,703 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/code/chollosite/daphne.sock
cholloproject-daphne-1  | 2023-08-12 09:30:14,704 CRITICAL Listen failure: Couldn't listen on any:b'/code/chollosite/daphne.sock': Cannot acquire lock.
cholloproject-daphne-1 exited with code 0
cholloproject-daphne-1  | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
cholloproject-daphne-1  | wait-for-it.sh: db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
cholloproject-web-1     | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
cholloproject-web-1     | wait-for-it.sh: db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
c
```